# Stop the cursor from jumping to the end of the line when typing a colon in the VS2017 C++ editor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, autoformatting

When I type a colon before the end of a word in VS2017, the cursor jumps to the end of the line:

[image: animated gif demonstrating the problem]

This only happens when the word is last on a line.

I don't see an option to disable this in the autoformatting settings:

[image: screenshot of the vs2017 c++ formatting settings]

Tried disabling all these checkboxes, but didn't solve the annoyance.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I feel constantly defeated by it.

Comment: Well, you can't get a much better explanation of the problem than that =P

Answer (score 2):

**Corrections：**

Delete the specific symbols in it, and it will be normal. These specific symbols will commit member list.

[image]